# How to change interval between labels in Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, charts, intervals, axis-labels

I have been trying to look for solution in specifying interval between labels on the x-axis. I found the solution easily on the web. 
Just click on the axis on the chart -> then click on Format axis to the right -> Axis options -> Labels -> Under Interval between labels I should be able to specify interval units.

In my case. There is No Interval Between Labels, it is missing. The only thing there is Label Position. How can I change the interval without it? or how can I add it under Labels?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When right clicking on the axis in question, choose the bottom option and a menu will open on the right side where you can adjust the interval.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: That works for the Y axis. I suspect the original question relates to the X axis of a non-XY chart, so the X axis is a series of labels. Under Axis Options, expand the Tick Marks or Labels section and see what settings you can control.